# use equation of bezier curve to find the point of the path when SKNode is moving in spritekit

Tags: objective-c, performance, uibezierpath

Recently I was coding in Spritekit
What I need is to find a point of the bezier curve while SKNode is moving follow the UIBezierPath.BTW the bezier curve just has one control point.
I use the equation of bezier curve to find the 't', and use this 't' to get the point,I found that my code is just fit with the "straight line" of the bezier curve.If there is a big curve, I would be wrong, I think the speed of SKNode is not constant.I am very pleasure to know where is not right or get other solution.
Here is my code, it is for testing.

```
-(void)setupTestCurve
{
    float ts =0.56f;
    float timeofmove = 5.0f;
    SKSpriteNode* arrow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blue_b_01"];

    arrow.scale = 0.8;
    arrow.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    [background addChild:arrow];

    CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(400, 400);
    CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(800, 100);
    CGPoint controlP = CGPointMake(100, 100);
    [ToolObjective setupTestCurve:(SKSpriteNode *)background startp:point1 endp:point2 anchorPoint:controlP];

    CGPoint ps = [ToolObjective get3dPointbezierInterpolation:ts startp:point1 controlp:controlP endp:point2];
    float twill = [ToolObjective get3dTofbezierInterpolation:point1 nowPoint:ps endp:point2 anchorPoint:controlP];

    SKAction *w = [SKAction waitForDuration:twill * timeofmove];
    SKAction *paction = [SKAction runBlock:^{
        [ToolObjective setupTestpoint:background startp:ps color:[UIColor redColor]];
    }];

    SKAction *m = [SKAction sequence:@[w,paction]];

    CGPathRef patharrow = [ToolObjective Get3dBezierPath:point1 endPoint:point2 anchorPoint:controlP];

    SKAction *moveBow = [SKAction followPath:patharrow asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:timeofmove];

    [arrow runAction:[SKAction group:@[m,moveBow]]];
}
```

here is the tool function

```
/*
add a bezier curve to the background
*/
+(void)setupTestCurve:(SKSpriteNode *)background startp:(CGPoint)startPoint endp:(CGPoint)endpoint anchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint
{
    UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:startPoint];
    [path addQuadCurveToPoint:endpoint controlPoint:anchorPoint];
    SKShapeNode *circle = [SKShapeNode node];
    circle.path = path.CGPath;
    [background addChild:circle];
}
/*
get point on a bezier curve with 't'
*/
+(CGPoint) get3dPointbezierInterpolation:(CGFloat)t startp:(CGPoint)startp controlp:(CGPoint)controlp endp:(CGPoint)endp
{
    CGFloat q0x = (1 - t) * startp.x + t * controlp.x;
    CGFloat q1x = (1 - t) * controlp.x + t * endp.x;
    CGFloat x = (1 - t) * q0x + t * q1x;

    CGFloat q0y = (1 - t) * startp.y + t * controlp.y;
    CGFloat q1y = (1 - t) * controlp.y + t * endp.y;
    CGFloat y = (1 - t) * q0y + t * q1y;

    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
/*
get 't' of a bezier curve with a point on this bezier curve
*/
+(CGFloat) get3dTofbezierInterpolation:(CGPoint)startp nowPoint:(CGPoint)nowp endp:(CGPoint)endp anchorPoint:(CGPoint)controlp
{
    CGFloat ax = (startp.x - 2 * controlp.x + endp.x);
    CGFloat bx = (2 * (controlp.x - startp.x));
    CGFloat cx = (startp.x - nowp.x);

    CGFloat tx1,tx2;

    CGFloat px = bx * bx - 4 * ax * cx;

    if (px >= 0) {
        tx1 = (-bx + sqrt(px)) / (2 * ax);
        tx2 = (-bx - sqrt(px)) / (2 * ax);
    }

    if (tx1 == tx2) {
        return tx1;
    }

    CGFloat ay = (startp.y - 2 * controlp.y + endp.y);
    CGFloat by = (2 * (controlp.y - startp.y));
    CGFloat cy = (startp.y - nowp.y);

    CGFloat ty1,ty2;

    CGFloat py = by * by - 4 * ay * cy;

    if (py >= 0) {
        ty1 = (-by + sqrt(py)) / (2 * ay);
        ty2 = (-by - sqrt(py)) / (2 * ay);
    }

    if (ty1 == ty2) {
        return ty1;
    }

    if (fabsf(tx1 - ty1) < 0.0001)
        return tx1;
    else if (fabsf(tx1 - ty2) < 0.0001) {
        return tx1;
    }
    else if (fabsf(tx2 - ty1) < 0.0001) {
        return tx2;
    }
    else if (fabsf(tx2 - ty2) < 0.0001) {
        return tx2;
    }
    return 0;
}
/*
get bezier curve path with just one anchorPoint
*/
+(CGPathRef)Get3dBezierPath:(CGPoint)startPoint endPoint:(CGPoint)endPoint anchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint
{
    UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    [path moveToPoint:startPoint];

    [path addQuadCurveToPoint:endPoint controlPoint:anchorPoint];
    return path.CGPath;
}
/*
add a point on bezier curve
*/
+(void)setupTestpoint:(SKSpriteNode *)background startp:(CGPoint)point color:(UIColor *)color
{
    SKShapeNode *cpoint = [SKShapeNode node];
    UIBezierPath *ppath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(point.x,point.y,10,10)];
    cpoint.fillColor = color;
    cpoint.path = ppath.CGPath;

    [background addChild:cpoint];
}
```

You can use these code in the project to test.
Thank you very much!

A day later I find that sknode is not constant speed moving follow the bezier path. Use this method.

```
for (float i = 0; i < 1.0001f; i+=0.10f) {
    CGPoint ps = [ToolObjective get3dPointbezierInterpolation: i startp:point1 controlp:controlP endp:point2];
    [ToolObjective setupTestpoint:background startp:ps color:[UIColor yellowColor]];

}
```

So the key problem is to find a way to make the sknode has a constant speed.
I will post my solution here.Or you have already known please tell me !

Comment: bezier curve :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: I think you need to extend SKNode custom class.Then You need add observation  on center  of that SKNode and  implement KVO observation context method where you will get all information about SKNode.

Comment: thank for you answer. I make a Tower Defence game. The monster is moving. I must know where this monster to go, so I use equation of bezier curve  to calc the position. But my code is just wrong with moving follow the big curve, the staight line or nearly is right.

Comment: You will get current position of Monster while moving using KVO observation on monster. Using that location you may calculate your curve.

Comment: You mean that use KVO to update every moving ? That is a great solution. But now if I just want to calc the position, how to solve this problem, because this solution is going well for the most part of the game

Comment: And What is the most important thing is that I must know what is position of monster during the 'bullet' move, Just like a sniper,  the "bullet" or “arrow‘ has a time to move, we must know the position of monster when the 'bullet' shot on it.